# Extension of scalars and completions

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, valuation-theory

Suppose that $A$ is a Noetherian *regular* (added later) local domain. Moreover $\widehat A$ is $\mathfrak m$-adic completion $\widehat A$ w.r.t the maximal ideal and $K$ is the fraction field of $A$.

Now, could you explain why the following two claims are true?

1) If $A$ has Krull dimension $1$ then $\widehat A\otimes_A K$ is a field (in particular it is $\widehat K$).

2) If $A$ has Krull dimension $\ge 2$ then $\widehat A\otimes_A K$ is not a field.

**Edit:** The question arises from the following geometric viewpoint:
$S$ is an algebraic *smooth* (added later) surface on a perfect field, $A=\mathcal O_{S,x}$ and $K$ is the function field. In $1)$ is $x$ a point of codimension $1$, and in $2$) $x$ is a closed point. I was told that in the first case the result is a field, but this is not true in the second case.

Comment: I do not think, for example, 1) is true without some hypothesis. It is easy to construct examples of such $A$ with the completion not a domain and then your tensor product will not be a field. In your edit, did you mean a smooth algebraic surface? If so, the answer is positive.

Comment: yes I mean smooth! Sorry, so $A$ is also regular!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\widehat{A}=B$. If $A$ is smooth,  $B$ is a regular domain and in particular $B\otimes_AK$ is a field if and only if for any non-zero prime ideal $P$ of $B$, $P\cap A\neq 0$. If $\dim A=1$, $B$ has only one non-zero prime ideal, which is maximal and the intersection with $A$ is the maximal ideal, hence non-zero.

For the second case, let me write down one example in characteristic zero, the general case is not very different. Let $A=k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$, so that $B=k[[x,y]]$. Consider the prime ideal generated by $y-xe^x\in B$. You can easily check that its intersection with $A$ is zero.

Comment: Dear @Mohan, how do you prove that result? Do you have any reference?

Comment: Which result (since there are two) do you mean?

Comment: The fact that $B\otimes K$ is a field if and only if for any nonzero prime the restriction to $A$ is nonzero.

Comment: @manifold Have you tried proving it? It is fairly easy.

Comment: Yes I managed. Thank you anyway.